GitLab pipeline job `tsc --pretty --noEmit` doesn't see relative paths to public folder in TypeScript Next.js though it works on my local machine
Everything works fine on my local machine tsc --prettier --noEmit check passes through. Building works well on both my local machine and GitLab pipeline. But when I try to execute tsc --prettier --noEmit in GitLab pipeline job, it throws the following error:
> tsc --pretty --noEmit
src/components/mainPage/AuthorPortrait.tsx:5:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../public/author-portrait.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
5 import authorPortrait from '../../../public/author-portrait.png';
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/components/mainPage/MainPageAboutCompanyImage.tsx:4:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../public/about-the-company-boy.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
4 import aboutCompanyBoy from '../../../public/about-the-company-boy.png';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/components/mainPage/MainPageHeaderImage.tsx:4:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../public/main-page-header-boy.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
4 import aboutCompanyBoy from '../../../public/main-page-header-boy.png';
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Found 3 errors in 3 files.
Errors  Files
     1  src/components/mainPage/AuthorPortrait.tsx:5
     1  src/components/mainPage/MainPageAboutCompanyImage.tsx:4
     1  src/components/mainPage/MainPageHeaderImage.tsx:4
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I have this structure of file in my project:

Below is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "svgr.d.ts",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.png",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

It doesn't work with @ aliases in GitLab pipeline as well.
Please, help me to solve this problem, because it's important to perform tsc check in a pipeline, before deploying.
